# How can I use a HammerJS pinch gesture on iOS without scrolling a page?

Tags: ios, cordova, ember.js, gesture, hammer.js

I'm using [Ember-Gestures](https://github.com/html-next/ember-gestures) which implements Hammer.js in a Cordova app to implement some simple gesture controls.

I'm running into a major problem whereby any gesture that triggers an animation (transition, transform, SVG animations), if the screen is scrolling any amount, that animation will freeze and be at its end state when scrolling is complete. In particular, I have an element on a vertically scrollable page which should (ideally) be able to be pinched in and out to expand it into multiple elements or back into one.

I'm familiar that as an optimization iOS freezes all animation during scroll. However, since pinch and swipe gestures can both slightly scroll the screen, this is terrible for user experience because elaborate transitions can be completely frozen if the user swipes, for example, slightly up and to the left rather than just directly left.

I've tried a few solutions to enable rendering during scroll like those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125610/how-to-keep-animated-gifs-animated-while-scrolling-on-ios-devices), but these don't seem to work on contemporary versions of iOS. I've also tried the hammerJS e.preventDefault() method to freeze scrolling during gestures called through the Ember-gestures extension, so my method looks like:

```
swipeLeft(e) {
    e.originalEvent.gesture.srcEvent.preventDefault()
    // Do stuff
},
```

...but this doesn't have any appreciable effect. (Maybe there's something wrong here? `gesture` had no `preventDefault()` method itself, and ember-gestures seems to try to abstract some of this away.

Is there any way I can either keep animations rendering during scrolling (this seems unlikely), or alternately STOP a page from scrolling right before performing an animation (and prevent scroll while it's executing)?

Alternately is there any way I can add constraints to what is interpreted as a "pinch" or "swipe" gesture such that those that would also be interpreted as scroll gestures are excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution here ended up being to add event handlers such that when the screen is touched with multiple fingers, the body is set to fixed position such that it's unscrollable for the duration of the touch (with the fixed position removed when touch is ended). I added the handlers to the `pinchStart` and `pinchEnd` events

I suspect there might be a more elegant solution out there, but for the purpose of disabling accidental scrolling while pinching so that D3.js animations won't freeze midway, this was a quick and effective fix.